# C++ AES Encryption getting truncated to 16 characters

Tags: c++, encryption

I've got a function that I worked on a while ago in C++ that does AES 256 encryption using CBC.

I wrote the method a while ago so I unfortunately can't remember where I got the code from, but I've since found that I have a problem where if the string being encrypted is over 16 characters, its only the first 16 characters of the string that get encrypted.

The code is below:

```
string Encryption::encryptOrDecrypt(string stringToEncrypt, Mode mode)
{
    HelperMethods helperMethods;
    try
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);

        unsigned char key[33] = "my_key";
        unsigned char iv[17] = "my_iv";

        if (mode == Decrypt)
        {
            stringToEncrypt = helperMethods.base64Decode(stringToEncrypt);
        }
        vector<unsigned char> encrypted;
        size_t max_output_len = stringToEncrypt.length() + 16 - (stringToEncrypt.length() % 16);
        //size_t max_output_len = 16 - (stringToEncrypt.length() % 16);
        encrypted.resize(max_output_len);

        EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, mode);

        // EVP_CipherUpdate can encrypt all your data at once, or you can do
            // small chunks at a time.
        int actual_size = 0;
        EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx,
            &encrypted[0], &actual_size,
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&stringToEncrypt[0]), stringToEncrypt.size());

        // EVP_CipherFinal_ex is what applies the padding.  If your data is
        // a multiple of the block size, you'll get an extra AES block filled
        // with nothing but padding.
        int final_size = 0;
        EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, &encrypted[actual_size], &final_size);
        actual_size += final_size;

        encrypted.resize(actual_size);

        char * buff_str = (char*)malloc(encrypted.size() * 2 + 1);
        memset(buff_str, 0, (encrypted.size() * 2 + 1));
        char * buff_ptr = buff_str;

        size_t index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index)
        {
            buff_ptr += sprintf(buff_ptr, "%c", encrypted[index]);

        }
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        if (mode == Encrypt)
        {
            string encryptedString = buff_str;
            free(buff_str);
            return helperMethods.base64Encode(encryptedString.c_str(), encryptedString.length());
        }
        else
        {
            string decryptedString = buff_str;
            free(buff_str);
            return decryptedString;
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        return stringToEncrypt;
    }

}
```

I've stepped through the code to see where the problem might be and I can't see any reason why, its probably something stupidly simple.

The `size_t max_output_len` is 768 (the actual string is 752) so this is +16 for padding I believe, but I'm not sure if this should 768 as well but as the method is setting this itself not sure.

The pointer `int final_size` that gets passed into `EVP_CipherFinal_ex` becomes 16 when that method completes and the `actual_size` is also 768 so not sure where the problem is.

Comment: In `EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, &encrypted[actual_size], &final_size);
        actual_size += final_size;` Does `actual_size` get updated to be larger than 0? If so, you're passing your output buffer at a position that is far from the beginning of the data. I'm only assuming that `actual_size` gets changed in `EVP_CipherUpdate` to have the "actual size" of the data; I'm not not sure how the cipher functions you're using work.

Comment: `actual_size` is initially 0 and then when `EVP_CipherUpdate` receives actual_size as a pointer it becomes 752, then after `EVP_CipherFinal_ex` is called `actual_size` becomes 768. Not sure what you mean though as `actual_size` is only used to resize the vector, its not used again as part of the output?

Comment: You are creating `encryptedString` from `char*` containing encrypted data. Is it possible that by chance the encrypted data has `\0` byte at position 17 and you get truncated string as a result?

Comment: It doesn't look like it from looking at the contents when debugging

Comment: I think I've found a way around it so have added an answer. Thanks for the suggestions, not sure why my work around works though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured the problem, although not 100% sure why this works and the original way doesn't.

I don't believe its a null byte from looking at the content of buffer when debugging but I've changed it to the following which seems to resolve it.

Instead of

```
string encryptedString = buff_str;
```

I have changed it to the following

```
int i = 0;
stringstream encryptedStringStream;

for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    encryptedStringStream << buff_str[i];
}
string encryptedString = encryptedStringStream.str();
```

Comment: How about `string encryptedString(buff_str, index);`? Or directly from `encrypted` if you don't mind casting: `string encryptedString(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&encrypted[0]), encrypted.size());`